# How to show only files using QFileSystemModel and QTreeView?

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I have tried few attempt to show only file names inside my folder and subfolder but no luck so far. Basically below is how my QTreeview looks like

[image]

Here, Folder structure is like :-

```
SV
  A_XML_Folder
   A_XML_Folder.xml
  B_XML_Folder
   B_XML_Folder.xml
SI
  A_Python_Folder
   A_Python_Folder.py
  B_Python_Folder
   B_Python_Folder.py
```

So far so good, but now i am only keen to get list of python and xml files like

```
A_XML_Folder.xml
B_XML_Folder.xml
A_Python_Folder.py
B_Python_Folder.py
```

My code is :

```
        self.mymodel.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllEntries) #QDir.AllDirs | 
        self.mymodel.setNameFilters(["*.py","*.xml"])
        self.mymodel.setNameFilterDisables(False)
        self.mymodel.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath()+'/Database')

        self.ui.treeView.setModel(self.mymodel)
        self.ui.treeView.setRootIndex(self.mymodel.index(QDir.currentPath()+'/Database'))
        self.ui.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.ui.treeView.hideColumn(1)
        self.ui.treeView.hideColumn(2)
        self.ui.treeView.hideColumn(3)
        self.ui.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.ui.treeView.setAnimated(True)
```

I tried all permo-combo but no luck so far, is there any other elegant way for the problem

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a model that searches all files in a directory tree and presents them as a list. I don't think `QFileSystemModel` offers this functionality. I recommend that you implement your own model by subclassing `QAbstractListModel`.

Comment: Yes titisjan, i did the same and now i am using QListView with QStandardItemModel and filling it with all xml and py files using os.walk. I will soon upload the answer. Thanks